# simple_html_dom response is empty

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I'm having trouble with certain web pages when using HTML dom. I've set the user agent and a stream opens but the response seems to be empty.

Something I have noticed about these pages is that there are unclosed tags in the HTML. Could this affect simple html dom?

My code is:

```
 <?php 

 include_once 'simple_html_dom.php';

 $url_to_compare = 'http://www.idigic.net/buy-instagram-followers/';

 ini_set('user_agent', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

 $html = file_get_html($url_to_compare)->plaintext;

 echo $html;

 ?>
```

Comment: _"Could this affect simple html dom?"_ It could. You might try cleaning up the HTML first with [`tidy::repairString()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/tidy.repairstring.php).

Comment: Not working! @AlexHowansky

Comment: Try using curl. Also I don't think that `ini_set` does anything.

Answer (score -2):

check this link

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

I think it's needful for u.

**file_get_html** its getting array so it does not display any content in echo. using print_r  may be work.

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Print_r does return something, but I cannot access any elements or plaintext which renders everything else useless.